# Create Spark Dataframe fails for Array of Type Any or _

Tags: arrays, scala, generics, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

While developing a Spark Unit Test, I am trying to create a Dataframe containing an Array. I really don't care what's in the Array (a complex data type in real life) as I'm just interested in its size.

```
val data = spark.createDataframe(Seq(
    ("a", 1, Array()),
    ("b", 2, Array())
)).toDF("columnA", "columnB", "columnC")
```

I get the following error that is related to the columnC (removing columnC it works fine): `scala.MatchError: Nothing`

So I tried using `Array[Any]()` and I got: `Schema for type Any is not supported`

So I tried using `Array[_]()` and I got: `unbound wildcard type`

So I tried using `Array[Object]()` and I got: `Schema for type java.lang.Object is not supported`

Finally, I decided to ask on Stackoverflow...

Comment: You may not care abut the type Spark does. To know how to store the array it has know the type and invoke correct encoder.

Comment: can you try Seq()

Answer (score 0):

DataFrames support a [limited set of data types](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types).  `Object` and `Any` aren't included.  You can use `Array[Int]()` (for one example) to make an empty array of a type that won't cause problems for schema inference.